# Response.seeOther returns blank screen

Tags: java, web-applications, jersey, appdirect

I need to redirect to a specific external url in my jersey web service

and I am using this method:

```
    public static Response redirectTo(String path) {
    URI uri;
    try {
        uri = new URI(path);
        return Response.seeOther(uri).build();
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

But it navigates to a white screen page and not to stackoverflow.com.

Why is it happening and how to fix it?

This method is called inside this method

```
@GET
    @Path("/login")
    @Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    public Response login(@Context UriInfo info, @Context HttpServletRequest request) {
...
String url = "http://stackoverflow.com";
redirectTo(url); 
}
```

the url of login method is called when triggering an event from AppDirect (via browser)

Comment: You probably need to provide more details. What do you mean by a white screen? Which client you use to access the REST resource which is supposed to return 303 with the `Location` header? How do you use this client to call this resource? Have you tried `curl` and checked whether it returns 303 with the `Location` header as expected?

Comment: I edited the question, no I didnt try the curl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up in adding the `@Context HttpServletResponse` res parameter to my method and calling this method `res.sendRedirect(urlApp);`

This is working as expected.